# Conversion to Dalvik format failed error for Android Grid View

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-sdk-2.1

I'm on the android bandwagon and started going through google's "view" tutorials. Here is what I'm using:
Eclipse Galileo
Android SDK 2.1
Java SDK 6.Something I think.

Everything was hunky-dory until I hit the grid view tutorial. I got errors all over the place when I started editing the "HelloGridview.java" File. I thought I'd fix it by following through with the next part of the tutorial, creating the ImageAdapter class, but it created more. I realized alot of my issues could be resolved by importing widgets which were not mentioned in the tutorial (i.e. android.widget.GridView, .ImageView, .BaseAdapter etc.) However, after all the reconciliation suggested by eclipse the files were finally showing no errors. I go to run it as an android app and bam, "Your project contains error(s)." window comes up. There are no errors showing on the files I've created. I cleared the error log and shut down eclipse and started again the error log now reads: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1. I'm a little lost at this point. I think I've included the required information. If you need to know more let me know.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of those examples on the Android developer site are a trifle out of date, and so it may be that the one giving you grief is no longer a great example to work from.

Try [this `GridView` sample](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Selection/Grid/) for something that definitely works on current versions of Android.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess it was a little naive to assume every example was going to function exactly right. However, I am surpised that a simple grid view app now doesn't work. I wonder if instead of being android problem it's an eclipse galileo adjustment...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Eclipse imported a jar in the java build path and this somehow caused the error.

Right Click o the project -> Java Build Path and make sure you have only once imported android.jar.